How to generate class file with Proto DataStore 1.1.1 protobufPlugin 0.9.4 com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin-lite/protoc 4.26.1 in simple project
I created HelloDataStore at Android Studio Koala with gradle 8.7. I am new to learn Proto DataStore. I checked codelab for proto DataStore but failed. Then I checked nia (now in Android) app and found use protoc and protobuf-kotlin-lite 4.26.1, I did follow codelabs insrtuctions to config my HelloDataStore project but seems I cannot generate class file because I had defined user_prefs.proto which details is below.
The UserPreferencesSerializer object file cat NOT resolve UserPrefs and build/generated/ have no source folder. HelloDataStore github branch here if you are interested.
libs.versions.toml
protobufPlugin = "0.9.4"
#protobufPlugin = "0.9.0"
#protobufPlugin = "0.9.1"
protobuf = "4.26.1"
#protobuf = "3.21.12"
#protobuf = "3.17.3"


// ...
protobuf-kotlin-lite = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protobuf-kotlin-lite", version.ref = "protobuf" }
protobuf-java-lite = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protobuf-javalite", version.ref = "protobuf" }
protobuf-protoc = { group = "com.google.protobuf", name = "protoc", version.ref = "protobuf" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
protobuf = { id = "com.google.protobuf", version.ref = "protobufPlugin" }

build.gradle.kts(:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.protobuf)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.wecanteen105.hellodatastore"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.wecanteen105.hellodatastore"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

// Setup protobuf configuration, generating lite Java and Kotlin classes
protobuf {
    protoc {
//        artifact = libs.protobuf.protoc.get().toString()
//        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.4"
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.9"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
                create("kotlin") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//androidComponents.beforeVariants {
//    android.sourceSets.register(it.name) {
//        val buildDir = layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile
//        java.srcDir(buildDir.resolve("generated/source/proto/${it.name}/java"))
//        kotlin.srcDir(buildDir.resolve("generated/source/proto/${it.name}/kotlin"))
//    }
//}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)

    implementation(libs.androidx.recyclerview)

    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)

    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewModel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewModel.savedstate)

    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore.pref)
    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore)
//    implementation(libs.protobuf.java.lite)
    implementation(libs.protobuf.kotlin.lite)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

user_prefs.proto
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.wecanteen105.hellodatastore";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message UserPrefs {
  // filter for showing / hiding completed tasks
  bool show_completed = 1;
}

UserPreferencesSerializer
object UserPreferencesSerializer:Serializer<UserPrefs>


proto folder should be stored in src/main/proto, not in src/main/java/proto as I did before. I was reminded by a great person from this issues.
